# R Find ratio of similar values across files in a directory

Tags: r

I have a series of .txt files in a directory that all have the same number of columns and column names with data that looks rougly like this example file:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | AMRO 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-14 13:10:00 | AMRO 1 | 4 |
| 2022-03-14 13:20:00 | DEJU | 5 |
| 2022-03-14 13:30:00 | MALL | 6 |
| 2022-03-14 13:40:00 | AMRO | 7 |
| 2022-03-14 13:50:00 | CHSP 1 | 8 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | AMRO | 40 |
| 2022-03-14 14:10:00 | AMRO | 50 |
| 2022-03-14 14:20:00 | DEJU 1 | 60 |
| 2022-03-14 14:30:00 | AMRO 1 | 70 |
| 2022-03-14 14:40:00 | AMRO | 80 |
| 2022-03-14 14:50:00 | CHSP | 90 |

For each file in the series of files in the directory how can I find the ratio of matching regular values in column 'Value1' and those with " 1" at the end? For example, for this particular file, there are seven values of 'AMRO' or 'AMRO 1' in 'Value1' and three of those are 'AMRO 1', so the ratio would be 3/7 or ~43%. I would want that value for each of the other values in Value1 including DEJU, MALL, and CHSP. Again, for DEJU that would be 1/2 or 50%, for MALL that would be 0/1 or 0%, and CHSP that would be  1/2 or 50%.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Base R solution

Here is a base R way with `tapply`.

```r
tmp <- sub("\\s*\\d$", "", df1$Value1)
with(df1, tapply(Value1, tmp, \(x) length(grep("\\d$", x))/length(x)))
#>      AMRO      CHSP      DEJU      MALL 
#> 0.4285714 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000

# tidy up
rm(tmp)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## `dplyr` solution

A `dplyr` solution follows the same algorithm, get rid of the final digit, group by that result and compute the proportions.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df1 %>%
  mutate(Group = sub("\\s*\\d$", "", Value1)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Prop = length(grep("\\d$", Value1))/n())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   Group  Prop
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 AMRO  0.429
#> 2 CHSP  0.5  
#> 3 DEJU  0.5  
#> 4 MALL  0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Many files

To process many files all in the same directory, first rewrite the code above as functions, then read in the data and process it with a sequence of `lapply` loops. Something like the following.

```r
f_base <- function(x, col = "Value1") {
  tmp <- sub("\\s*\\d$", "", x[[col]])
  with(df1, tapply(x[[col]], tmp, \(y) length(grep("\\d$", y))/length(y)))
}

f_dplyr <- function(x, col = "Value1") {
  x %>%
    mutate(Group = sub("\\s*\\d$", "", !!sym(col))) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarise(Prop = length(grep("\\d$", !!sym(col)))/n())
}

f_base(df1)
#>      AMRO      CHSP      DEJU      MALL 
#> 0.4285714 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000

f_dplyr(df1)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   Group  Prop
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 AMRO  0.429
#> 2 CHSP  0.5  
#> 3 DEJU  0.5  
#> 4 MALL  0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And process the files. (Untested, since there are no data files.)

```
files_vec <- list.files(path, pattern)
# or maybe `read.csv`
df_list <- lapply(files_vec, read.table, header = TRUE)
prop_list1 <- lapply(df_list, f_base)
prop_list2 <- lapply(df_list, f_dplyr)
```

---

## Data in `dput` format

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Date = c("2022-03-14 13:00:00", "2022-03-14 13:10:00", 
"2022-03-14 13:20:00", "2022-03-14 13:30:00", "2022-03-14 13:40:00", 
"2022-03-14 13:50:00", "2022-03-14 14:00:00", "2022-03-14 14:10:00", 
"2022-03-14 14:20:00", "2022-03-14 14:30:00", "2022-03-14 14:40:00", 
"2022-03-14 14:50:00"), Value1 = c("AMRO 1", "AMRO 1", "DEJU", 
"MALL", "AMRO", "CHSP 1", "AMRO", "AMRO", "DEJU 1", "AMRO 1", 
"AMRO", "CHSP"), Value2 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 40L, 50L, 
60L, 70L, 80L, 90L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct for a single file, so thank you! However, how do you do this for each file in a directory?

Comment: The updated code to process many files is spot on, so thank you for taking the time to help me today. In case people have blanks in some rows, for the code: df_list <- lapply(files_vec, read.table, header = TRUE) I would fix to: df_list <- lapply(files_vec, read.table, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)